# Can't change statusbar to white in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I want a single controller to have white text in the status bar. I've set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES in my plist.

The controller I want to have white status text is embedded in a UINavigationController so overriding preferredStatusBarStyle doesn't seem to work. Also, setting barStyle doesn't seem to do the trick either:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
```

I'm on iOS 8. Does anyone know the answer? Thanks in advance.